# How to Compare two histograms of images?

Tags: c#

I convert two histograms into integer arrays and now I have two arrays of size array1[65536] and array2[65536] in which values are range from 0 -255 at different indexes. Now I like to match two these arrays so that I could get the result of how much these two images are matched ?????
Please help me asap.

Comment: What do you mean by "match these arrays"? Do you just want to measure the Earth mover's distance between the two histograms?

Comment: Can we get more information on what you want? Do you want to know what percentage of the values in array1 exactly match the corresponding values in array2?

Comment: An histogram for an image with 256 tones of gray should correspond to an array of 256 elements. Why do you havce array[65536] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't compare if the images are matched. As Tergiver said, an image histogram is a graphical representation of the tonal (lightness) distribution in an image.

If you want to compare your histograms and check how much they differ from one another, you can do as in the following example (this is an example with a 5-element-sized array, just to simplify):

```
int[] array1 = {0,255,100,200,78 };
int[] array2 = {255, 0, 250, 15, 34 };
float[] diff = new float[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    diff[i] = ((float)Math.Abs(array1[i] - array2[i])) / 255;
}

float degreeOfDiff = diff.Sum()/array1.Length*100;
bool sameDistribution = degreeOfDiff == 0;

Debug.WriteLine(degreeOfDiff + "%");
Debug.WriteLine(sameDistribution);
```

I will emphasize that this will **not** check if the images are equal.

Comment: Is this solution will give me the difference that how much image1 is different from image2 ?? Because my last phase is image recognition in which I'm stuck here to compare just two histograms.

Comment: It will compare the two **histograms**, in this case `degreeOfDiff` will show how much % one histogram is different from the other one. Without knowing what kind of histogram this is and what kind of information it holds, I cannot assure you it will compare images. It will certainly compare `int`s ranged from 0 to 255 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

An image histogram gives you the number of times a given color appears in an image. Imagine image A as a black vertical line of 25 pixels and image B as an image of a black box 5x5 pixels.

Both A and B have exactly the same histogram, but are clearly not similar images.

Comment: They are if his metric for similarity is based on the histogram. I think it really depends on what he means by "similar". If he means he wants to know whether the two original images "look alike" (for some fuzzy value of looking alike), then you are correct that this cannot be done by comparing the histogram.

Answer (score 0):

The question's a bit vague, but if what you want is the symmetric difference then here's a one-line LINQ query for it:

```
int[] foo = new int[] { 1,2,3 };
int[] bar = new int[] { 4,5,6 };

int distance = foo.Zip(bar, (x,y)=>Math.Abs(x-y)).Aggregate( (x,y)=>x+y );

Console.WriteLine("Symmetric difference between foo and bar: {0}", distance);
```

There may be fancier ways to compute similarity. It depends in large part on what images you want to consider "similar". I suspect you may also get better results with a smaller array (i.e. putting together similar shades) so that images that are "almost" the same color register as "similar".

**edit**: It looks like [**Earth mover's distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) is what you want: Wikiedia's page lists image comparison as a good application of EMD.

> An early application of the EMD in computer science was to compare two
>   grayscale images that may differ due to dithering, blurring, or local
>   deformations.[4] In this case, the region is the image's domain, and
>   the total amount of light (or ink) is the "dirt" to be rearranged.
>
> The EMD is widely used in content-based image retrieval to compute
>   distances between the color histograms of two digital images. In this
>   case, the region is the RGB color cube, and each image pixel is a
>   parcel of "dirt". The same technique can be used for any other
>   quantitative pixel attribute, such as luminance, gradient, apparent
>   motion in a video frame, etc..

The Wikipedia page also has pseudocode for an algorithm to compute EMD, I believe that is the correct answer to your problem.